# How to tell UITextView is dirty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

Currently, I test whether a UITextView is dirty or not by:

```
if ([self.textView.undoManager canUndo]) ...
```

Is this always correct? Or is there any `isDirty`-like method in `UITextView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to lots of things with the `UITextViewDelegate`

Check out the [UITextViewDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) for comprehensive details

`- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

`- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

`- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`

There's more to do with `shouldBegin` and `shouldEnd` editing, and also selection changes.

Hope that helps out.